# How to prevent the creation of a temporary file tmp.edb during opening ESENT database?

Tags: database, temporary, esent

When I try to open ESENT database, a temporary file "tmp.edb" is created in program dir. I can change the path using JET_paramTempPath but, I can't find how to disable it.

Can I read DB without creation of temporary files?

Here's my code:

```
JetSetSystemParameter(nil, nil, JET_paramDatabasePageSize, iPageSize, nil);
JetSetSystemParameter(nil, nil, JET_paramRecovery, nil, 'Off');
JetCreateInstance(&FInstance, nil);
JetInit(FInstance); //Here file "tmp.edb" is created

JetBeginSession(FInstance, &FSession, nil, nil);
JetAttachDatabase(FSession, FFileName, JET_bitDbReadOnly);
JetOpenDatabase(FSession, FFileName, nil, &FDatabase, JET_bitDbReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to suppress creation of a temporary database file.

It is a fundamental concept of how ESENT operates, and cannot be turned off.